# Connect to SharePoint Online with ADAL From WCF

Tags: sharepoint-online, wcf, adal, azure-ad

I am trying to connect to SharePoint Online with ADAL from a WCF Service that is hosted in Azure as App Service.

I configured the App, got a client ID and Secret, enables AAD auth. This works, if i browse the site in a webbrowser. I can login, get redirected to my Site where the WCF is hosted.

The WCF tries to connect to my SPO site with ADAL. I get the Access Token and add it to the client context like this

```
ctx_.ExecutingWebRequest += (sender, args) =>
             {
                 AuthenticationResult token = ServiceHelper.GetAccessToken(ClientID, AppKey, TenantIDTitle, TentantID);


                 args.WebRequestExecutor.RequestHeaders["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token.AccessToken;
             };
```

There is a a token that I get, so no errors or anything. when I try to load the web and the execute the Context, i get an 401 unauthorized, but I don't get why. Why would I get a token if I am not allowed to access SPO with it.

Am I getting the Token wrong?

```
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY);
var credential = new ClientCredential(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);
var result = (AuthenticationResult)authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(API_ID_URL, credential).Result;
var token = result;
return token;
```

Comment: What value does API_ID_URL contain?

Comment: Hi Tanmay. The API_ID_URL is: https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/mysitecollection. It is the same value as the one I entered in the manage.windowsazure.com App setting in the APP_ID_URI field

Comment: Your `APP_ID_URL` is probably correct but note that it should be the URL of the resource you are requesting (In your case SharePoint). You have APP_ID and resource ID as same, may be try changing your APP_ID to something else (can be anything e.g `https://your-azure-tenant.com/this-app-name`) and pass the SP URL in your `AccquireTokenAsync` Your authority should be of the form `login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID` client and client secret should be from the Azure AD app you registered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was doing the whole thing the wrong way:
I changed it to first 
GetAuthorizationRequestUrlAsync to login and then AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync with the code I get from the first method.